# How can I automate testing my TV application in real TVs?

Tags: android, tizen, television, webos

I'm new to TV apps, and I've built some simple TV apps. And now I want to find a way to test the apps in the actual 4-5 TVs I own. The point is to do automation tests and have access to "console" messages, like I have when I do this in emulators. Unfortunately, I haven't found any relative software. The TVs which I have are: 2 LG, 1 Samsung and 1 Android and one older FireTV.

I have looked into docs for Android, WebOs, and Tizen and I found nothing. I found just for FireTV the "Amazon Web App Tester (Fire TV)" but because I have an old Fire TV I want more to check out the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really help with Tizen OS or WebOS, but on Android TV/Fire OS this should be relatively simple. You need to setup an ADB connection and you will be able to debug and build your apps directly on the Android TV device.

1. Enable Developer options on the tv
2. Enable ADB debugging in the developer options
3. Go in the wifi settings of the TV and take note of the IP address (and make sure that your PC and TV are connected to the same wifi)
4. On your Android Studio console/computer terminal type:

   adb connect <TV IP address>
5. Allow the connection in the popup that prompts on the TV

You should be able to now see the device in Android Studio and use that as a build target.

Comment: Great! Thank you for that! I just need to find something for the other 2 now.